# Clicking a textview to change fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

I am trying to build my first android app using Kotlin but I am stuck on a very simple situation. I am using Kotlin android extensions and I am getting a Null pointer exception.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGoToRegisterFrag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_sign_in"
        android:text="@string/haven_t_registered_yet"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

With this I used

```
tvGoToRegisterFrag.setOnClickListener {
        goToRegister()
    }
```

I do know I can use

```
tvGoToRegisterFrag?.setOnClickListener {
        goToRegister()
    }
```

To get rid of crashing but still I am not sure why the object is null and does not do anything when clicked. All of this is done in a Fragment if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason you may be getting NPE is that you are using it in the wrong lifecycle method I was having a similar error when using it in `onCreateView` instead you should only use Kotlin android extensions in `onViewCreated`.

Comment: Thank you it worked when I added it to `onActivityCreated`! so I cannot use them anywhere else is what you are saying? or just not in `onCreateView`?

Comment: you can use Kotlin android extensions in any lifecycle where the fragment view hierarchy has been completely created, and the first lifecycle method and the recommended one is `onViewCreated`